# Renaming index.js to index.jsx in react app

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and i started an app using create react app.When i try to rename index.js to index.jsx, I'm getting an error saying 
"Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/qbuser/Desktop/onChat-final/new/chat/client/src/index.js'".
What should be done? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Rename it back to index.js. The file can still contain JSX.

Or run "eject"/ use WebPack, then you can customize anything.

Comment: can u please suggest me with an example on using webpack? I tried ejecting. But then what? I have no idea.please?

Comment: So if ejecting is not a good idea for me, is there an other way to do this?

Comment: So cant i use index.jsx format with out ejecting as you mentioned before?

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Misleading answer.

Comment: @denexapp has the correct answer below this one.

Answer (score 47):

It's a bug with create-react-app dev server: it can't handle renaming of index.js to index.jsx and vice versa. Just restart your dev server

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just stop the dev server and start it again. It picks up index.jsx then.

Answer (score 9):

You need to restart the app after renaming. I fail to find a reason for this but the solution works.

1. Stop your app by pressing `Ctrl + C`.
2. Then restart the app with `npm start`.