# how to import component in index.js in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have created component folder in src folder and tried to write simple greeting program for that I have created 3 files:

1. GreetUser.jsx
2. index.jsx
3. index.html

while compiling it is showing that could not find required index.js file.

I have written 3 files in Component folder and have imported GreetingUser module in the index.jsx file and while compiling it is showing that could not find required index.js file.

**1.GreetingUser.jsx**

```
import React , {component}  from 'react';
class GreetUser extends component
{
    render()
    {
        return <h1>Greetings from suraj!!!!</h1>;
    }
}
export default GreetUser;
```

**2.index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import GreetUser from './Component/GreetUser.jsx';


ReactDOM.render(<GreetUser/>,document.getElementById('aaa'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

> Could not find a required file.
>     Name: index.js

Comment: Can you share the index.html file? probably you're loading in the a script `index.js` instead of `index.jsx`.

Comment: How did you create your react app? with create-react-app cli?

Comment: yes create-react-app React-app(app name)

Comment: Is the filename GreetUser.jsx  or GreetingUser.jsx?

Answer (score -1):

Fundamentally, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the React.createElement(component, props, ...children) function.
index file must with .js extension and not jsx is not react component.
index.js file in a folder lets you perform an import from the folder implicitly without specifying the index.js in the import statement – just like how web servers will serve up the index.html in a folder without you needing to explicitly put the index.html in the URL.

You can modify webpack configuration if you need it.
You can look at additional  answers: [Renaming index.js to index.jsx in react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016976/renaming-index-js-to-index-jsx-in-react-app) and [Why does create-react-app creates both App.js and index.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493069/why-does-create-react-app-creates-both-app-js-and-index-js)

Comment: do i need to write app.js too?

Comment: No. it's a pattern in create-react-app

Comment: i have deleted all pre loaded files in src folder and created new folder and in that created GreetUser.jsx file. Is there any compulsion that index.js must be n src foldr only

Comment: I think you received answer for your current question here.

Comment: yes...but could you suggest some documentation about react..i have read their official site but not sufficient..

Comment: What do want to know? React, create react app, webpack. Post in  new  question.